# Куда сохранять python файл, вызывающий c++ dll?

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

Я пишу программу вызывающую из python C++ dll.
Подскажите пожалуйста куда именно нужно сохранять python файл, что бы код заработал? Я слышал что нужно сохранять его в той же папке, но не понимаю в какой именно.

Comment: dll должен лежать в том же каталоге, где находится скрипт, в системном каталоге или в одном из каталогов указанных в переменной окружения PATH. А скрипт может лежать там, где вам удобно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а разве C++ библиотеку нельзя импортировать из любого места указав путь к ней? Она же импортируется в питоне как обычный модуль.

Comment: Куда хочется, туда и сохраняйте. Только укажите  путь к длл.

Comment: @outoftime я описываю случай для `CDLL("MathFuncs.dll")`